# Joi field value evaluation based on other two fields

Tags: validation, joi

I am not sure whether I can do this in validation block itself but I am giving a try.

I have something like this

```
body: joi.object({
  AssignedUser: joi.string().allow('').optional().default('').description('userName'),

  fromLocation: joi.string().required().description('From Location'),
  toLocation: joi.string().required().description('To Location'),
```

})

my question is when the values of `fromLocation` and `toLocation` are equal then use the value that passed for `AssignedUser` otherwise set it to empty string ''.

how can I go about it?

I tried passing a function parameter to

```
AssignedUser: joi.string().allow('').optional().default(() => {return fromLocation === toLocation? AssignedUser: ''}, 'description').description('userName')
```

my question is that this default block code executes only if `assignedUser` is empty but I want this block of code to be executed every time and evaluate the value based on `fromLocation` and `toLocation`

any help?